# Java String comparison issue with blank spaces

Tags: java, if-statement

I invoke using java some web service which returns some values to me.
Those values are some attribute names which I successful receive. I put the returned values in database.
For example the values I retrieved are:

> DSLAM port
>
> Interfejs na ISP

So when I look in the database those values are stored in DB as `DSLAM port` and `Interfejs na ISP`.
That is how I received them and that is how they are stored in DB (so only with one blank space between the words).

So I'm receiving those values from a web service but when I try to do a comparison additional in the class:

```
if ( attribute.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Interfejs na ISP") ) {
     System.out.println("attr2");
}
```

or

```
if ( attribute.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("DSLAM port") ) {
     System.out.println("attr3");
}
```

I am not having the System Print lines to my console, `if` is always `false`.
What can be the problem and how can I solve it?
This is a really strange behavior for me. Attributes are stored correctly and only when I try to compare it I get strange behavior. The `if` clause is never `true`. Can there be some issue with the language format?

Additionally if I try with single word:

```
if (attribute.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Telefon"))
                    {   System.out.println("attr5");
                        
                        
                    }
```

Then it writes in System Out.
So with sinlge word it seems it does not have problems

Comment: Try `trim()`on attribute just to be sure.

Comment: One silly question: you did try this with an `else` and, you did see the alternative printout, right?

Comment: Maybe ther are trailing and/or leading blanks in the string. try `attribute.trim().equalsIgnoreCase`

Comment: use Trim() my friend.

Comment: Or Print `attribute` to check what values you are getting..

Comment: Debug your program & check the values

Comment: What is the result of `System.out.println(attribute)`? And to analyze deeper, tell us the outcome of `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(attribute.getBytes("UTF-8")))`.

Comment: I added trim attribute.trim().equalsIgnoreCase but situation is the same. Also I added else and it always goes into ELSE.

Comment: Also I put the System Out Print Line and it writes Interfejs na ISP and DSLAM port

Comment: One important Update if i do this attribute.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Telefon") then IF is TRUE. So only for single word it does not have issue

Comment: I think the above comments are eluding to some sort of encoding issue, which is probably what's happening here. However, if you believe the problem to relate to the number of spaces inbetween the words, then why not try: `attriibute.replaceAll(" ", "").equalsIgnoreCase( "DSLAMport" )` This is a bit hacky, but it might give you more information on what's going on.

Comment: Could it be a hard, non-breaking space U+00A0? `if (attribute.matches("(?i)\\s*Interfejs[\\s\\u00a0]na[\\s\u00a0]ISP\\s*")) {` Sometimes used in text for HTML to prevent wrapping.

Comment: Output a serialization of the byte array behind the values of "attribute" to see exactly what characters it contains. This will also help you catch stuff like nbsp for whitespace etc.

Comment: I tried with replace attribute.replaceAll(" ", ""); but it does not recognize as blank space and it does not replace blank space...I tried to do work around on that way but it also does not work although it will be acceptable workaround. please what can be done?

Comment: @Dejan see comment by hiergiltdiestgu. Output the bytes of your value.

Comment: Interfejs na SP is: [B@52d052d0

Comment: Can you have some conclusions based on this?

Comment: I turned my comment and the reply to your comment into a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Output a serialization of the byte array behind the values of `attribute` to see exactly what characters it contains. This will help you catch stuff like nbsp for whitespace etc. When this is done, you can change your string matching to what you actually get back from the database, or tune your persistence to produce straight forward values.

It is not enough to just println the variable, instead, you have to iterate over all the buckets in the array and output them in hex or dec - your target output is something like "[44, 53, 4C, .. ]", which would correspond to "DSL..". To convert the byte array to a hex representation, you can use this snippet, or as an exercise, try it on your own:

```
public static String convertToHexString(byte[] data) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        int nibble = (data[i] >>> 4) & 0x0F;
        int two_nibbles = 0;
        do {
            if ((0 <= nibble) && (nibble <= 9))
                buf.append((char) ('0' + nibble));
            else
                buf.append((char) ('a' + (nibble - 10)));

            nibble = data[i] & 0x0F;
        } while (two_nibbles++ < 1);
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

Now when you have that output, take an [ascii table](http://www.electronicdeveloper.de/AllASCIITabellen.aspx) to look up which values are contained in the string and change your ifs depending on what is actually contained in the Strings. Possibly by using a matching regex. 
Chances are the whitespaces are some non-trivial blank characters like `&nbsp;` (Hex: A0), but it's also possible that you are having an encoding problem. Feel free to post the hex values if the character tables don't help.